# Register Bean Validation ValueExtractor with Spring/Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, validation

**Setup**

I have a custom container class:

```
public class PatchField<T> {

    private boolean isSet;
    private T value;

    public PatchField(T value) {
        this.isSet = true;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public PatchField(boolean isSet, T value) {
        this.isSet = isSet;
        this.value = value;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I have a request which I would like to use as a @RequestBody in Spring REST endpoint. Do note that I annotated String with @NotEmpty. That means I need a custom ValueExtractor.

Request:

```
@ApiModel
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class Request {

    private PatchField<@NotEmpty String> name = PatchField.empty();

    //Getters and Setters

}
```

I have created PatchFieldValueExtractor as per [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#_implementing_a_code_valueextractor_code):

```
public class PatchFieldValueExtractor implements ValueExtractor<PatchField<@ExtractedValue ?>> {

    @Override
    public void extractValues(PatchField<?> originalValue, ValueReceiver receiver) {
        receiver.value(null, originalValue.getValue());
    }
}
```

**Problem**

However, I cannot find a way to register **PatchFieldValueExtractor** with Spring or customize automatically created Validator like I can, for example **RestTemplate** via **RestTemplateBuilder**. If I annotate **PatchFieldValueExtractor** with **@Component** in Spring Boot, it does not get picked up automatically. I get the following error:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000197: No value extractor found for type parameter 'T' of type com.example.PatchField.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraints.addValueExtractorDescriptorForTypeArgumentLocation(MetaConstraints.java:145) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraints.create(MetaConstraints.java:61) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.createTypeArgumentMetaConstraint(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:795) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.lambda$findTypeUseConstraints$2(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:783) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findTypeUseConstraints(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:784) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findTypeArgumentsConstraints(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:762) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findTypeAnnotationConstraints(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:581) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findPropertyMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:237) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getFieldMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:225) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.retrieveBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:133) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:124) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanConfigurationForHierarchy(BeanMetaDataManager.java:232) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:199) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:166) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:889) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.validateIfApplicable(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:266) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:137) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Ofcourse, I could, just create my own **Validator Bean**. I have tested it and it works:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomValidator {

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
                .configure()
                .addValueExtractor(new PatchFieldValueExtractor())
                .buildValidatorFactory();
        return validatorFactory.getValidator();
    }
}
```

However, I fear that by doing so, I [opt-out](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.java) of current or future AutoConfiguration "goodies" that I am not aware. For example, there are nuances with RestTemplate and RestTemplateBuilder, which can lead to unexpected runtime behaviours as outlined in this [article](https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/spring-boot-why-you-should-always-use-the-resttemplatebuilder-to-create-a-resttemplate-instance-d5a44ebad9e9). Thus I am reluctant to go this route. Is there a better version on how to customize Validator?

**Sources I have looked**

[**Spring Framework Documentation. Bean Validation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation). Per documentation:

> You can use the LocalValidatorFactoryBean to configure a default Validator as a Spring bean.
>
> The basic configuration in the preceding example triggers bean validation to initialize by using its default bootstrap mechanism. A JSR-303 or JSR-349 provider, such as the Hibernate Validator, is expected to be present in the classpath and is automatically detected.
>
> **Additional Configuration Options**
>
> The default LocalValidatorFactoryBean configuration suffices for most cases. **There are a number of configuration options for various Bean Validation constructs, from message interpolation to traversal resolution. See the LocalValidatorFactoryBean javadoc for more information on these options.**

[**LocalValidatorFactoryBean**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html)

This API does not contain clear information how could I register custom ValueExtractor.

[**Spring Boot Documentation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).
No mentioning of LocalValidatorFactoryBean or how to customize it.

Comment: [These docs](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-validationroutine-valueextractorresolution) suggest multiple ways to register `ValueExtractor`s. 2 of which are via XML

Comment: I can register ValueExtractor via ValidatorContext#addValueExtractor(ValueExtractor<?>) as showed in the question. However, I am asking, if there is a way to register new ValueExtractor with Spring without recreating Validator it as a Bean.

Comment: As shown in the linked docs there are 2 ways to do it via XML which would be exactly what you asking for

Comment: Is there any way to that programmatically without XML?

Comment: You could try to fetch the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` from the spring context and add validators

Comment: As stated in question "This API [LocalValidatorFactoryBean] does not contain clear information how could I register custom ValueExtractor."

Comment: @Mr.Robot did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem with you and can't find a way to register a custom ValueExtractor with spring

Comment: @jk47 unfortunately no :( But I fetch my model from database and then patch it, then run it through javax/jakarta validator, thus the final model is still correct.

Comment: @jk47 I have found the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To register custom `ValueExtractor`, one has extend `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` :

```
@Component
public class CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean extends LocalValidatorFactoryBean {

    @Override
    protected void postProcessConfiguration(Configuration<?> configuration) {
        super.postProcessConfiguration(configuration);

        configuration.addValueExtractor(new PatchFieldValueExtractor());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can register in Resources/META-INF/services/javax.validation.valueextraction.ValueExtractor

```
com.yourpackagename.PatchFieldValueExtractor
```